# Why is my Miracast display about a minute behind my computer?

Tags: windows-10, miracast

I am trying to send my computer's display over to my TV by `duplicating` it, but my TV shows what I was doing about a minute ago instead of what I'm doing right now. That's honestly obnoxious and I was wondering why this is happening and how can I fix it?

I am using Miracast and Windows 10.

Comment: Does miracast work over wifi?

Comment: I assume it does. I don't have the best Internet if that helps.

Comment: Miracast uses WiFi Direct. Personal opinion: Miracast sucks so I suggest you give up on it.

Comment: I don't know of any other ways I could wirelessly connect my PC to my television though.

Comment: There are none, of course. The thing is, I haven’t experienced Miracast working fine, ever. It’s not even consistent lag. Sometimes it’s almost in sync, seconds later there’s a 10-20s delay – all during the same session! It really recommend you look for a different way to get whatever content you want to your TV screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows 10 you should not use any other third-party drivers because Windows 10 has its own Miracast driver.

Find out if your T.V is supported by the Windows MiraCast driver.

Comment: Miracast isn’t related to the Internet in any way. It’s also a standard, so interoperability is guaranteed.